# Is there a way to add a "Go to today" to a JavaFX DatePicker?

Tags: datepicker, javafx-11

The title says it all: I have a JavaFX DatePicker and am looking for a way to add a button which, upon a click to it, goes to the current date or at least the current month.

Is there a way to do this?

BTW, I'd like to have this button *inside* the DatePicker, maybe above the month calendar.

Do I have to modify the skin?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would work for you 
`datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.now());`

Inside the button action function you can add this code to set the datepicker to the local date

Comment: Is there a way to place this button inside the DatePicker?